# Variable embedded source AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

i'm currently making a little memory game with multiple themes for cards and backgrounds. I've managed to make it possible for 1 set of images to embedded into the game but I want to make it possible to have more themes. In order to make this happen I use this 8 times for differen cards:

```
public var c1:String;
[Embed(source = c1)]
public var Card1:Class;
```

With this I made a constructor as such:

```
public function Theme( _c1:String)
{
c1 = _c1;
}
```

Now in a different class for specified themes I use this constructor as such:

```
var Fruit:Theme = new Theme (".../lib/Apple.jpg");
```

Now I believe what this does it makes a new object of Theme with a string c1 which is the source for the picture and then uses that String source to make a picture off of it by putting it in the Embed source, but I get these error messages:

```
c1 does not have a recognized extension, and a mimeType was not provided. 
Unable to transcode c1
```

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do here is pass a variable (which happens in runtime, after the swf is compiled) to Embed metatag which is preprocessed at compile time (before the application is aware of actual theme string value).

There are 2 solutions. A new swf file per each theme. You define the resource for the theme as a constant, not a variable:

```
[Embed(source = 'path/to/resource')]
```

If you want to use one swf, you must rethink your application design and load theme at runtime, by initializing a loader, fetching resource, creating a new `Theme` from that resource and then start actual game code.

```
class Theme extends EventDispatcher {

   public static const THEME_READY = 'themeReady';

   private resource:Bitmap;

   public function Theme(resourceUri:String) {
      loadResource(resourceUri);
   }
   private function loadResource(path:String):void {
      var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest(path));
      loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onResourceLoaded);
   }
   private function onResourceLoaded(e:Event):void {
      e.target.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLeTE, onResourceLoaded);
      this.resource = e.target.content; 
      initialize();
      dispatchEvent(new Event(THEME_READY));
   }
}
```

game initialization:

```
var themeResource:String = 'path/to/resource.jpg';
var theme:Theme = new Theme(themeResource);
theme.addEventListener(Theme.THEME_READY, initializeGame);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that would work.

In flash you can either embed the image with :

```
[Embed(source="picture.jpg")]
private var Picture:Class;
```

or can dynamically load(at runtime) as an external image with the [loader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html).

I would suggest embed each image as a class & implement the selection logic in your theme class.